# Unable to split String using |

Tags: string, scala

When I split a String using `,` works as expected :

```
  val line1 = "this,is,a,test"                    //> line1  : String = this,is,a,test
  val sLine = line1.split(",")
```

however if I use `|` the String is split into its character elements and added to array :

```
val line1 = "this|is|a|test"                    //> line1  : String = this|is|a|test
val sLine = line1.split("|")                    //> sLine  : Array[String] = Array("", t, h, i, s, |, i, s, |, a, |, t, e, s, t)
```

Why is this occurring because of | character ?

Comment: Try escaping it via `"\\|"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pipe is a special regex character, I believe you need to escape it like so `"\\|"` in order for it to work

Answer (score 4):

possible solutions

```
val sLine2 = line1.split('|')
```

because `'` denotes a character, a single character, `split` does not treat it as a regexp

```
val sLine2 = line1.split("\\|")
```

to escape the special alternation `|` regexp character.  This is why it isn't working.  `split` is treating `|` as a zero width regexp and so the string is vapourized into its component characters

Answer (score 1):

```
scala>  val line1 = "this,is,a,test"
line1: java.lang.String = this,is,a,test

scala> line1.split(",")
res2: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(this, is, a, test)

scala> var line2 = "this|is|a|test"
line2: java.lang.String = this|is|a|test

scala> line2.split("\\|")
res3: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(this, is, a, test)
```